# No type hints for dataclasses

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, annotations, python-dataclasses

I want to have a class that aggregates several dataclasses in one entry point, but faced a problem with type hints from Pycharm. It doesn't show me suggestions about class arguments.

```
@dataclass
class FirstDataClass:
    some_attribute: int


@dataclass
class SecondDataClass:
    some_attribute_2: int


class Aggregator:
    @property
    def first_class(self):
        return FirstDataClass

    @property
    def second_class(self):
        return SecondDataClass


FirstDataClass(some_attribute=3)  # all works well here, Pycharm shows me the hint about attribute
Aggregator().first_class(some_attribute=3)  # but here Pycharm says that Unexpected argument is 
                                            # given and doesn't show any suggestions

first_class = Aggregator().first_class      # although get_type_hints shows the correct arguments
print(typing.get_type_hints(first_class))   # {{'some_attribute': <class 'int'>}
```

[Screenshot of a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqcU7.png)

I tried to use annotations like -> Type[FirstDataClass] or ClassVar[FirstDataClass] - it doesn't help. Is it a bug of Pycharm and is there any way to receive hints?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in the IDE's static analysis, here is the relevant ticket in the PyCharm's issue tracker:

- [PY-36375](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36375) Unexpected argument false positive when reassigning a dataclass (PEP 557)

Unfortunately, I don't know any suitable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug, as previously mentioned. I am also not sure of the use case with properties, however you can for now, use class attributes instead. This should allow the IDE to offer *type hinting*  as desired in this case.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Final, Type, get_type_hints


@dataclass
class FirstDataClass:
    some_attribute: int


@dataclass
class SecondDataClass:
    some_attribute_2: int


class Aggregator:
    first_class: Final[Type[FirstDataClass]] = FirstDataClass
    second_class: Final[Type[SecondDataClass]] = SecondDataClass


FirstDataClass(some_attribute=3)  # all works well here, Pycharm shows me the hint about attribute

Aggregator.first_class(some_attribute=3)  # works well here too!


my_second_class = Aggregator().second_class

print(my_second_class(some_attribute_2=42))  # SecondDataClass(some_attribute_2=42)
print(get_type_hints(my_second_class))       # {'some_attribute_2': <class 'int'>}
```